# Action potential: why called "depolarization" when polarity is reversed, not removed?

Tags: action-potential

During an action potential, the voltage shifts from the resting potential of -70 mV, to +30  mV, to then fall return back to the resting potential again of -70 mV. This reverse of the polarity, what is the reason it came to be called "depolarization", as in, removed polarity?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While the cell is polarized (in the positive direction) at the height of the action potential, it has been *de*polarized from its resting, negatively charged state, meaning the original polarity has been lost or reversed. In my mind, the slight (30mV max) positive polarization for that brief period of time is kind of an "overshoot" of neutral charge, just like during recovery the potential exceeds -70mV for a period of time before coming back to the resting state.